# Spring JPA + H2 issue

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2

I started making a simple spring boot application.

My first step was to make use of Spring JDBC support, with default H2 in-memory database.
For sample data, I had schema.sql and data.sql in src/main/resources.

So when spring launches, it also executes these 2 scripts and populate H2 database, which I can access via H2 console.

All works fine, and I can test correct data being returned by controllers.

Then I added JPA support by adding:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But ever since, those 2 scripts(schema.sql, data.sql) are no more executed.

Does JPA dependency cause it? And what is the workaround to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` you can set the following property in `application.properties` and it should work if you have hibernate and that is causing the problem (most probably):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema
>   or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.

The schema.sql is a spring based initialization process and having hibernate in classpath will conflict with this.So, you can try disabling hibernate auto config like this.
Official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

If that it not the case please share entire pom file.